# Scalajs + Angularjs how to use external javascript plugin

Tags: angularjs, scala.js

I'm trying to use an external JavaScript plugin in my ScalaJs Angular directive.
I don't know the best way to do that so for the moment I added this function to the `window`.

the javascript plugin looks like this:

```
(function(){
   "use strict";
   SmartCrop.crop = function() {
     //some function
   }
   SmartCrop.options = {
     //options
   }
   //...

   window.SmartCrop = SmartCrop  // I added this line
})()
```

But I don't know how to access window.SmartCrop in my scalaJs code.

I tried to do that in my directive, but without success (please take a look at the comments I wrote in the following code):

```
@JSExport
@injectable("smartCrop")
class SmartCropDirective(window: Window) extends ElementDirective with TemplatedDirective {

  override val  templateUrl = "assets/templates/smartcrop/smartcrop.html"

  override def link(scope: ScopeType, elements: Seq[Element], attrs: Attributes): Unit = {
      // I can found window.SmartCrop in my console if I log window
      console.log(window)
      // this line is not working but I'm looking for something similar:
      window.SmartCrop.crop()
  }
}
```

So, I'm looking for the good way to use this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@js.native
object SmartCrop extends js.Object {
  def crop(): Unit
}

...
SmartCrop.crop()
```

For more information, see the [Write JavaScript facades guide](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html).